# Partial Range issue in CompactDatePickerStyle SwiftUI

Tags: date, datepicker, ios14, swiftui-form

I am using DatePicker in a Form in SwiftUI(iOS 14). By default I am able to get CompactDataPickerStyle Date Picker.
The picker shows the current date highlighted. It also allows to choose previous dates.
Now, I specify a partial range using the 'in' parameter to allow the user to choose only future dates as below:

```
DatePicker("From", selection: $startDate,in: Date()... , displayedComponents: .date)
```

The date picker does not display the current month when opened but a future date.

Anyone else facing the same issue or has some idea on how can we resolve this.

Comment: please show how you are initializing the `startDate` variable. I think that's the problem.